# The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library

Tags: android

Please excuse my bad English, I'm french :)

So, I have got a problem with my android project...
I've got this error The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library[...]

I've made a lot of search on Google and :
- The library is an android library (the case is checked)
- The library is "called" in my project (Android tab then Add)
- I build on Java 1.6

And I still have this error (and for all included projects !)

Could you help me ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still valid, but I faced a similar problem.

The project that you have imported into your workspace as a `Library project` needs to be built first. One way to check if that is the case is if the `bin/` folder is empty in the project. If it is not, you first need to build the library project. Building it will cause the missing library dependency errors to also go away.