# The container Android Dependencies references non existing library /home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/bin/appcompat_v7.jar

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to android and this question is asked several times in this forum. But I couldn't able to solve the problem with the answers in those post. So I am posting my problem here to get your support

I have created a new appcompat library in eclipse juno as mentioned in the below link.
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html
(**the *Referenced Libraries* in this new support-library has both android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar**)

then i created my first Android project HelloWorld. 
(the **Android Private Libraries** in this folder has both android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar

When I buitd this project, it failed with the below error
**"the android dependencies references non existing library /home/user/workspace/appcompat_v7/bin/appcompat.jar"**

In the below post it was mentioned that the appcompat library project needs to be built first, before using it as reference in other projects.
[The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172539/the-container-android-dependencies-references-non-existing-library)

so i built the library project. It fails with error
**/home/user/Developer_Share/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'**.

could you please advise how to resolve these issues so that the project HelloWorld is built successfully.

Comment: You might consider switching to [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) which makes including these libraries (and many others) equivalent to adding a single line to your application, rather than attempting to use the now deprecated Eclipse Android plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project with minSdkVersion as 14. This is the minimum version that do not require appcompat_v4 and v7 libraries and it is just a workaround for this issue.